# having "Description: Too few items in renditions." when compiling

Tags: iphone, xcode, validation, assets

I have the error:

```
.../Assets.xcassets: error: Multiple validation errors occurred.
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: Too few items in renditions.
        Description: Too few items in renditions.
        Description: Too few items in renditions.
        Description: Too few items in renditions.
        Description: Too few items in renditions.
```

when trying to compile in Xcode

Any suggestion about how to fix it?

Comment: Check your image names. Any duplicates? Also try a clean and then build again.

Comment: thank you aheze! it was the problem: duplicate file names (physically)